# Не своевременное удаление частиц в анимации

Tags: javascript, html, анимация, canvas

Я делаю с помощью canvas анимацию с потоком из 0 и 1. Цифры должны исчезать за пределами экрана, но почему-то некоторые исчезают даже не долетев до границ экрана, хотя я поставил проверку с запасом. Когда пробую выводить высоту, пишет всё правильно, а рисование как будто идёт не так как должно. Кто знает, пожалуйста подскажите в чём дело.

Вот код.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const width = 1300;
const height = 650;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var inRad = function(angle) {
  return angle * Math.PI / 180;
};

//анимация
let arr = [];
let timeCtr = 0;
let speed = 2;

const animation = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  if (timeCtr === 0) {
    let object = {
      x: Math.random() * (width + 600) - 600,
      y: -10,
      angle: Math.random() * 45,
      rotate: 0,
      nmb: String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2))
    }
    object.dx = Math.cos(inRad(object.angle)) * speed;
    object.dy = Math.sin(inRad(object.angle)) * speed;
    arr.push(object);
    timeCtr = 10;
  }

  timeCtr--;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].x += arr[i].dx;
    arr[i].y += arr[i].dy;

    if (Math.floor(arr[i].y) > height + 40) {
      arr.splice(arr[i], 1);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(arr[i].x, arr[i].y);
    ctx.rotate(inRad(arr[i].rotate));
    arr[i].rotate++;
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillStyle = "White";
    ctx.shadowColor = "White";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
    ctx.fillText(arr[i].nmb, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animation);
};

window.onload = animation;
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

canvas {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: я бы посоветовал не изменять длину массива вообще, только двигать элементы, а когда они улетают за правую границу - переносить из за левую

Comment: `arr[i]` - объект, не может конвертироваться в число, поэтому этот вызов `arr.splice(arr[i],1)` всегда эквивалентен `arr.splice(0, 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно проверить индекс элемента, который удаляется каждый раз:

```
console.log(arr.indexOf([...arr].splice(arr[i],1)[0])); // Всегда 0
```

Поэтому `arr.splice(arr[i], 1);` просто заменил на `arr.splice(i, 1);` и вроде все работает:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const width = 1300;
const height = 650;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var inRad = function(angle) {
  return angle * Math.PI / 180;
};

//анимация
let arr = [];
let timeCtr = 0;
let speed = 2;

const animation = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  if (timeCtr === 0) {
    let object = {
      x: Math.random() * (width + 600) - 600,
      y: -10,
      angle: Math.random() * 45,
      rotate: 0,
      nmb: String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2))
    }
    object.dx = Math.cos(inRad(object.angle)) * speed;
    object.dy = Math.sin(inRad(object.angle)) * speed;
    arr.push(object);
    timeCtr = 10;
  }

  timeCtr--;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].x += arr[i].dx;
    arr[i].y += arr[i].dy;

    if (Math.floor(arr[i].y) > height + 40) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(arr[i].x, arr[i].y);
    ctx.rotate(inRad(arr[i].rotate));
    arr[i].rotate++;
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillStyle = "White";
    ctx.shadowColor = "White";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
    ctx.fillText(arr[i].nmb, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animation);
};

window.onload = animation;
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

canvas {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: _Предположу, что в этом случае JS пытается привести arr[i] к числу, затем к boolean и уже его к числу_ - не понял эту часть

Comment: да, для первого аргумента вызывается внутренняя функция ToInteger, которая, вызывает внутри себя ToNumber, и если ToNumber возвращает NaN, то ToInteger вернет +0. Подробнее в [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-tointeger)

Comment: Алгоритм `.splice` тоже в спецификации :) http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-array.prototype.splice

Comment: там же вроде сразу алгоритм идет :) по ссылке :)

Comment: Алгоритм, шаговый. Только как это понять: 1. `Let O be ? ToObject(this value).`
2. `Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).`?

Comment: Просто определение значений :)

Comment: Ну понятней стало теперь много)) Вроде ассемблера расписаны все действия с памятью?

Comment: Не, это скорее псевдокод словами описанный, что-то вроде: _Пусть O будет результатом ToObject(...)_ и т.д.

Comment: Мощно, но пока мне не все там дается, не думаю, что я часто в нее заглядывать буду)) Спасибо за полезную информацию.